# JPA: How to map only one property from another entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Phone {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String number;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

The relationship between a person and a phone is one to one.

How could I access only the phone's number in the Person entity mapped by the phone's id

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    // ???
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

The reason for not mapping the whole entity is because in some more realistic entities there are too many properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, but something like this might be acceptable:

```
public class Person {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id")
    private Phone phone;

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phone.getNumber();
    }

}
```

Although you have mapped the whole object, not just the single property, you have only exposed the single property you want. The other stuff is hidden.

Alternatively, do it at the DB layer using a View:

```
create view person_with_phone as
select p.id, p.name,f.number 
from person p
join phone f on f.id=p.phone_id
```

and then have an entity class to match the view. You'll need to turn off schema creation in your JPA implementation.

Comment: This seems plausible